# Creating init script from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, init

I am trying to create a init script, from a shell script.  But the problem is that the resulting init script doesn't carry the variables associated with "$" symbol from shell script.

For example. 
The following function in shell script gets translated to

```
setup_sysd () {
cat << EOF > /etc/init.d/example
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

start() {
   echo -n "Starting ${DESC}: "
   cd ${WORK_DIRECTORY}
   $EXAMPLE
   RETVAL=$?
   [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch -- "$LOCK"
   return $RETVAL
}

exit $RETVAL
EOF
```

gets copied as,

```
start() {
echo -n "Starting : "
cd 

RETVAL=0
[  -eq 0 ] && touch -- ""
return 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use single quotes around here-doc delimiter `'EOF'` to avoid process expansions

```
cat << 'EOF' > /etc/init.d/example
...
EOF
```

However there are still quoting problems in sh script generated:

```
cd ${WORK_DIRECTORY}
```

should be

```
cd "${WORK_DIRECTORY}"
```

also how are defined variables DESC, LOCK, finally variables should be lowercase.